# SFDX CLI export more than 10k records

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, data-export

I'm trying to export records from an object that holds 20k records, and I'm using the `sfdx force:data:tree:export` command but it returns a max of 10k records.

How do I export the remaining records, and append it to my existing JSON file?

Command: `sfdx force:data:tree:export -q "QUERY" -d data/t1-afr/ -p --loglevel fatal`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to extract all records using the `soql:query` command instead and output to csv.

E.g. `sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "QUERY" -r csv > data/filename.csv`

Comment: also works for json ```sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "QUERY" -r json > data/filename.json```